# Export csv with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, bytearrayinputstream

I want to ensure that my written CSV-file is encoded using UTF-8:

```
public StreamResource getExportDataAsCsv() {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            List<Object[]> exportData = getExportData();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            buffer.append(someData);
            byte[] bytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        }
    }, "MyExport.csv");
}
```

Unfortunately the found methods/ways to do so don't fit to my interface. Any ideas?

Comment: What means >"don't fit to my interface"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```